# How to upload folder and sub folder to the s3 by using python

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
import os

def uploadDirectory(image,testing-reports-image):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(image):
        for file in files:
            s3C.upload_file(os.path.join(root,file), testing-reports-image, file)
```

******Here testing-reports-image is mine s3 bucket name and image is folder**
when i am running this script i am getting error    def uploadDirectory(image,testing-reports-image):
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
How can i fix this**

Comment: This question is about a syntax error, it's not actually about uploading folders to S3, the title is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a dash `-` in names, the `testing-reports-image` parameter has several.

Comment: i have removed - but file is not uploaded

Comment: Your question is about the syntax error. If you have further errors, try asking another question about those errors after you have debugged and tried to fix the problem yourself